# How to determinate the minimum period of oscillation for a physical pendulum?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, harmonic-oscillator, moment-of-inertia

> A physical pendulum consists of a thin homogeneous rod of length $l$, suspended by a point $O$ at a distance $x$ from the center of gravity ($x<\frac{l}{2}$), oscillating in a vertical plane. **For which value of $x$ the period of oscillation is minimum?**
>
> [image]

I'm having trouble to solve this.
Denoting the torque by $\Gamma$ and the angular displacement by $\theta$, we would have:

$$ \Gamma = I\ddot\theta$$

$$ \Gamma = -mgx\sin\theta \approx -mgx\theta$$  (considering $\theta \ll 1$)

Both equations give the O.D.E

$$\ddot\theta+\frac{mgx}{I}\theta = 0$$

We would have solutions of the form $$\theta = A\cos(\omega t+\phi)$$ where $$\omega = \sqrt{\frac{mgx}{I}}$$

The period is $$\tau =\frac{ 2\pi}{|\omega|} = 2\pi\sqrt{\frac{I}{mgx}}$$

The moment of inertia $I$ would be $\frac{ml^2}{12}+mx^2$, by the parallel axis theorem.
I stopped here because I can't find what value of $x$ would minimize the period $\tau$.
How should I continue? If someone knows a different approach to solve this, it would be also welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are really close. At this point you have an expression for $\tau$ which you need to minimize with respect to $x$ - you just didn't take the last step, which is writing $I$ as a function of $x$ in that expression:

$$\tau = 2\pi \sqrt{\frac{\ell^2/12 + x^2}{gx}}$$

A minimum / maximum will occur when $\frac{d\tau}{dx}=0$. To keep your life simple it's worth noticing that if $f(x)$ has a maximum at $x_0$, then $\sqrt{f(x)}$ will also have a maximum at $x_0$. So we can take away some of the fluff and look for the maximum of

$$\frac{\ell^2/12 + x^2}{gx}$$

I trust you can differentiate this w.r.t. x and set the result = 0 and solve. Finally, you need to convince yourself that you have found a maximum (either by plotting the graph, or by computing the second derivative and showing it's <0).

Comment: $x=\frac{l}{2\sqrt{3}}$. I was not taking away $2\pi$ and the square root because I thought this could alter the results...

Comment: Do you see why that would change the value of the maximum but not the place where it occurs? Basically that is because multiplication and the square root function are both monotonic- if the input is bigger the output is bigger and vice versa. Or think chain rule: $f(g(x))'=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$ which has a zero when $g'$ has a zero.

Comment: An interesting thing I realized later: the result is exactly the radius of gyration of the rod around an axis which passes by the center. Solving for a general rigid body (with  $I = Mk^2 + Mx^2$) yields $x=k$ for a minimum period, where $k$ is radius of gyration (in the particular example, $k=\sqrt{\frac{l^2}{12}}$)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to put the moment of inertia $$I(x) = a + b  x ^ 2$$ into the formula for $\tau$, then differentiate with respect to $x$ and find out the $x$, for which $$\frac{d \tau}{dx} = 0$$

Comment: Where did you get this moment of inertia?  It is not correct; in fact $a$ and $b$ are not even defined for this problem.

Comment: Above, I needed to re-edit my I(x) formula, someone edited it after my first answer to your question, but he got it wrong. Thereofore, the else possible extremum was vanished -- until today ;-) Btw. I was new here, and did not know how to format my post (Latex I assume by now .. ). Regards.